# Google-managed SSL stuck on renewing

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

As of tonight, I have been reconfiguring my app to deploy via Google App Engine, instead of Heroku - which uses an ephemeral file system.

The website seems to be working as intended (both frontend and backend), however I am unable to host it on my custom domain.

I have provided all of the proper DNS records to my registrar on https://domains.google.com, including 4 fields for IPv4, and 6 for IPv6

The CNAME record provided has the host name of www, and the data is ghs.googlehosted.com
Please help, thanks.

EDIT: Not 6 fields for IPv6, there are 4 fields for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: We need the domain name and each resource record to test. Otherwise, use online DNS testing tools to validate your DNS resource records.